# I had 1 table view and three labels in it

Tags: ios, uitableview, loading

Here is my problem I had a table view which consists of 3 three labels in it (test1, test2, test3) which comes from webservice. I want to load all the three labels in a single table view. Here is my code below :

```
for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
                     projectNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
                     taskNames = [entries valueForKey:@"TASk_NAME"];
                     subtaskNames = [entries valueForKey:@"SUBTASK_NAME"];
                 }
                 NSLog(@"project : %@", projectNames);
                 NSLog(@"taskNames : %@", taskNames);
                 NSLog(@"subtask : %@", subtaskNames);
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [projectNames count];

}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identitifier = @"Cell";
    DLPTSTableViewCell * cell = [tableView
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identitifier
                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    long row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = projectNames[row];
    cell.textLabel.text = taskNames[row];
    cell.textLabel.text = subtaskNames[row];

    return cell;


}
```

I want to load the test 1 in projectnames array, test 2 in tasknames array and test 3 in subtasks arrays..

Please help me out.

Comment: where you have defined all three UILabels(test1, test2, test3)..?

Comment: test1 , test2 and test 3 are not the labels but it is the data retriving from webservice

Comment: You are providing the text in same attribute i.e. `cell.textLabel.text`

Comment: You can create custom table cells as you wish.. Please check this tutorial.. this will help you.. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: okey.. so where is your labels, for displaying values..?

Comment: Make a custom cell to display the three different texts.

Comment: May I know how it is?

Comment: Yes it might be a problem I will try to keep the data in different labels and give a try. Will be back in 5 min after it is done @ Himanshu

Comment: @KiranKumar: Himanshu Joshi is saying right. make custom Cell with different UILable with different Tag. and display it in UITableView.

Comment: you can take help from here http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Thank you guys I guess the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating custom UITableViewCell with name "DLPTSTableViewCell" then first create three labels i.e yourLabel1, yourLabel2, yourLabel3 and use this below code :

```
-(DLPTSTableViewCell *)getNewCell
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DLPTSTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    DLPTSTableViewCell *cell;
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[DLPTSTableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell= (DLPTSTableViewCell  *)currentObject;
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    DLPTSTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [self getNewCell];
    }


    // for displaying values

    cell.yourLabel1.text = your first value;
    cell.yourLabel2.text = your second value;
    cell.yourLabel3.text = your third value; 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: comments says everything